# Writing from right to left in Trello?

Tags: trello

Our studio uses Trello and we mostly write in Hebrew to each other. Since we can not change the writing from right to left, most messages that contain English letters come out completely wrong.

If it is possible that I might have missed something, I would enjoy some help on this issue. If not, then I'm sure Trello would be a better place with the option of right to left writing.

Answer (score 7):

You can use [this stylish thing](http://userstyles.org/styles/79861/trello-rtl-mini-support?r=1355246624), that I wrote to solve the same problem (it works in Firefox and souhld work on Chrome too).

It's fine for me. If you see need for some other RTL fixes that I didn't recognize, you can ask for it in the link above.

Comment: I created an account for this site just to upvote this answer.

Comment: This Stylish thing.... I love people who write code and then just kinda shrug it off as nothing much. אתה תותח!

Comment: @TomGranot-Scalosub: :) No one asked fixes... I thought no one is using it...

Comment: People are my friend.... beauty of the web.

Answer (score 3):

I just wrote a [Trello RTL Support (Github)](https://github.com/ykh/trello-rtl-support) client-side solution. 
It's still new, but has really help me.

**Update (2014-12-15):** 
I added Hebrew language as another RTL language to supported list.

Comment: Great very helpful!

Comment: It's my pleasure. let me know your ideas about it

Answer (score 2):

One thing you *can* do is mix [Unicode rtl/ltr overrides](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr9/#Explicit_Directional_Overrides). If the default is RTL, use the LTR override to write in English, and use the RTL override to get back to normal.

Ltr is `&#8237`, rtl is `&#8238`

For example, ahead I've done `first &#8238; second &#8237; third &#8238; fourth` in HTML and copy-pasted the result:

```
 first ‮ second ‭ third ‮ fourth
```

If you copy-paste the line into some text area and play around with the arrow keys on your keyboard, you'll find it pretty easy to realise that "second" and "fourth" are indeed rtl.

So just give everyone a page that has these overrides in copyable format. Since these are zero-width characters, it may make more sense to have two buttons like:

```
 <button onclick="prompt('Hit Ctrl-C and close','\u8237\u8237')">LTR</button>
 <button onclick="prompt('Hit Ctrl-C and close','\u8238\u8238')">RTL</button>
```

on some webpage and let your users copy the characters from there. Note that the characters have zero width, so they won't see anything in the box.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem but I fixed it without any extension or options. Just be careful to write the first word of your comment in your RTL language and then Trello makes that comment totally RTL. But if the first word is in English, the whole card will be LTR, and thus writing an RTL language mixed with LTR will make that comment look quite messy.